# Not able to see Manage Jenkins option on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, configuration

I was able to see standard Jenkins dashboard (configuration dashboard). Suddenly after a couple of logins, the manage Jenkins option is gone. All that I see is  \People

Build History

Credentials

I am not able to spin builds or make changes. How can I make sure that all those options come back. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling as well. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Also removed  <useSecurity>false</useSecurity> in the config.xml file

Comment: Do you have several Jenkins home folders on your machine? Maybe you disabled the security in the wrong one :(